# How to decorate an immutable object graph from scala case classes

Tags: json, scala, playframework, immutability, case-class

I'm reading structured JSON, using Play Frameworks' JSON Reads to build up an object graph with case classes.

An example:

```
case class Foo (
                       id: Int,
                       bar_id: Int,
                       baz_id: Int,
                       x: Int,
                       y: String
                       )
{
  var bar: Bar = null
  var baz: Baz = null
}
```

After building the Foo, I must come back later and decorate it by setting bar and baz. Those are defined in other JSON files and only known when all parsing is complete. But this means Foo can't be immutable.

What is the "right" way in Scala to make an immutable object, and then a decorated version of it, without repeating every field of Foo multiple times, over and over?

I know several ways that feel wrong:

- make "bar: Option[Bar]" and "baz: Option[Baz]" case class parameters, and then I can use "copy" to make new versions of the Foo class with them set to something; but then I have to check them every single time they're accessed - inefficient, unsafe, not able to make a DecoratedFoo that just is guaranteed to have the right structure
- make a second case class that is a copy-paste of all the structure in the first, but adding the two extra decorated parameters - but this means echoing the entire parameter list in the definition, and again when creating instances of it
- Case class inheritance is apparently controversial, and in any case also appears to require me to repeat every single parameter anyway, in the subclass constructor?
- Make a non-case superclass listing the common case class parameters. Then extend it in the case class. But this would seem to still require repeating every single parameter in the subclass constructor as well.
- I see blogs with people talking about this problem and using reflection at runtime to populate the base attributes of their decorated copies - this avoids echo but now you have no type safety, specifying attribute names as strings, overhead, etc...

Surely Scala must have a way to let people compose more complicated immutable objects out of simpler ones without having to copy each and every part of them by hand?

Comment: This is a pain point for me as well. It seems to me that the general problem is declaring a core data model and then, in a DRY way, defining derived/augmented models that are transformations of the original one. So far, I've not found a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `Option` and type parameters you can flag your case class, and track whether the processed fields are empty, statically:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

object Acme {
  case class Foo[T[X] <: Option[X] forSome { type X }](a: Int,
                                                       b: String,
                                                       c: T[Boolean],
                                                       d: T[Double])

  // Necessary, Foo[None] won't compile
  type Unprocessed[_] = None.type
  // Just an alias
  type Processed[X] = Some[X]
}
```

Example use case:

```
import Acme._

val raw: Foo[Unprocessed] = Foo[Unprocessed](42, "b", None, None)

def process(unprocessed: Foo[Unprocessed]): Foo[Processed] =
  unprocessed.copy[Processed](c = Some(true), d = Some(42d))

val processed: Foo[Processed] = process(raw)

// No need to pattern match, use directly the x from the Some case class
println(processed.c.x)
println(processed.d.x)
```

I used this once in my current project. The main problem I encountered is when I want `Foo` to be covariant.

---

Alternatively, if you don't care about the bound on `T`:

```
case class Foo[+T[_]](a: Int, b: String, c: T[Boolean], d: T[Double])
```

then you can use `Foo[Unprocessed]` or `Foo[Processed]` when you need a `Foo[Option]`.

```
scala> val foo: Foo[Option] = processed
foo: Acme.Foo[Option] = Foo(42,b,Some(true),Some(42.0))
```

Comment: I'm kind of astounded by Scala that this is possible. Unfortunately I can't get it to compile. Your type statements for Unprocessed and Processed fail with "expected class or object definition." I've noticed if I put them in the body of Foo {} they compile, but then your example use case does not work, as Processed/Unprocessed symbols are unknown.

Comment: @user2057354 Yes, you should put the type declarations inside an object (not inside the Foo class). Then you can import them when needed. It could be in the package object of Foo's package for example, or Foo's companion object.

Comment: I think this is so cool. And that does get it compiling and running. But it does not work with JSON Reads, in the scenario I described. Having the additional fields/parameters breaks the Reads ("missing arguments for method apply in object Foo" - since I now have extra fields/attributes on Foo that aren't in the JSON). This is the case even if I specify a default "None" value for c or d, which seems wrong.

Comment: E.g. 

  implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo[Unprocessed]] = (
    (__ \ "a").read[Int] and
      (__ \ "b").read[String]
    )(Foo[Unprocessed])

...doesn't work, and perhaps can't be made to work?

Comment: @user2057354 Use `Reads.pure`. Something like `implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo[Unprocessed]] = ( (__ \ "a").read[Int] and (__ \ "b").read[String] __.read(Reads.pure(None)) and __.read(Reads.pure(None)))(Foo[Unprocessed])` (maybe with some additional typing). You can also write another apply method: `(a, b) => Foo[Unprocessed](a, b, None, None)`.

Comment: Wow. OK - I will try that ASAP! I have been pouring over the documentation on playframework and the Reads API ( https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads ) - is there some place "Reads.pure" is documented that I missed it? I apologize if there is something I should have been reading all along!

Comment: @user2057354 Not documented, but it's shown on the companion object of the Reads trait (click on the "t" on the top to switch between companion and class / trait).

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't work. `implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo[Unprocessed]] = ( (__ \ "a").read[Int] and (__ \ "b").read[String] and __.read(Reads.pure(None)) and __.read(Reads.pure(None)))(Foo[Unprocessed])` results in "missing arguments for method apply in Object Foo."

Comment: I experimented with supplying e.g. __.read[Option[Boolean]](Reads.pure(None)), but this didn't work. If I have to specify a new apply method with redundant listings of parts of Foo, then I have made a new echo off Foo's components (which unfortunately defeats the purpose of this exercise).

Comment: Ah, I think I found the answer. It needs to be `implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo[Unprocessed]] = ( (__ \ "a").read[Int] and (__ \ "b").read[String] and __.read(Reads.pure(None)) and __.read(Reads.pure(None)))(Foo[Unprocessed] _)` - that last _ is what made the difference for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a new trait for the processed types, a class that extends that trait, and an implicit conversion:

```
case class Foo(bar: Int)

trait HasBaz {
    val baz: Int
}

class FooWithBaz(val foo: Foo, val baz: Int) extends HasBaz

object FooWithBaz {
    implicit def innerFoo(fwb: FooWithBaz): Foo = fwb.foo

    implicit class RichFoo(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
        def withBaz(baz: Int) = new FooWithBaz(foo, baz)
    }
}
```

So then you can do:

```
import FooWithBaz._
Foo(1).withBaz(5)
```

And, although `withBaz` returns a `FooWithBaz`, we can treat the return value like a `Foo` when necessary, because of the implicit conversion.

Comment: I'm fascinated by this approach. But it doesn't compile, and I'm afraid, since I am still just grappling with what you are trying to do here, that I can't figure out the problem with it yet.

Comment: Error:(13, 16) Play 2 Compiler: 
Foo.scala:13: RichFoo is already defined as (compiler-generated) method RichFoo
 implicit class RichFoo(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
                ^

Comment: That error seems utterly bizarre and unhelpful - I am still learning about implicit conversion and apologize if the solution is obvious?

Comment: Implicit classes have to be inside some other class or object.  I think that might be what's causing the error.  I was playing around with this in the REPL, where the rules for implicits are slightly different. Look at my change now (I moved `RichFoo` into the `FooWithBaz` object).

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't compile. I get a "Error:(16, 20) value class may not be a member of another class
    implicit class RichFoo(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
                   ^"

Comment: This code compile for me with scalac with version 2.11.2.  What are you using?  By reading that error message, is seems like making `RichFoo` not extend `AnyVal` may help, but then you lose some efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

One other strategy might be to create yet another case class:

```
case class Foo(
  id: Int,
  bar_id: Int,
  baz_id: Int,
  x: Int,
  y: String
)

case class ProcessedFoo(
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
  baz: Baz
)
```

Comment: I see. And perhaps that is the least of all evils, although it requires indirection for every reference to foo.